# 吉川線 (yoshikawa-sen) is translated as meaning "neck markings indicative of strangulation". What's the origin for this term (yoshikawa in particular)

Tags: meaning, words, etymology, names

To my knowledge, 吉川 (yoshikawa) serves only as a name. And yet, for some reason, 吉川線 ("yoshikawa lines" as it were) has the meaning of marks on the neck usually indicative of strangulation https://jisho.org/search/yoshikawasen . Is there a story about why such a meaning came about to "yoshikawa-lines"? E.g. there was a mass murderer named Yoshikawa who strangled many victims.

For what it's worth, I came across the term in Summertime Render (an anime)

Comment: Not trying to sound snarky, but did you try looking it up? https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%89%E5%B7%9D%E7%B7%9A

Comment: @Leebo I didn't want to sift through japanese articles, because my kanji skills are shit >.<. But I think I got the important part. Thanks! I'll write up an answer

Answer (score 4):

According to [Japanese wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%89%E5%B7%9D%E7%B7%9A):

> 名称の由来は、日本・警視庁の鑑識課長を務めた吉川澄一（1885年 -
> 1949年）が、ひっかき傷が他殺の証拠にあると着目し、学会で発表した事にちなんでいる。

Roughly translated: "The origin of the name comes from the fact that Chouichi Yoshikawa (1885-1949), who served as the head of the forensics section of the Tokyo Metropolitan Police Department, focused on the fact that such markings were evidence of a murder, and made a presentation at an academic conference."